# Extracting a childView and repositioning it inside of a new parentView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, frame, bounds

I’m trying to rip a view from a stackView that is embedded in a scrollView and then reposition said view in the same location but in another view at the same level in the view hierarchy as the scrollView.

The effect I’m trying to achieve is that I’m animating the removal of a view— where the view would be super imposed in another view, while the scrollView would scroll up and new view would be added to the stackView all while the view that was ripped fades out.

Unfortunately, achieving this effect remains elusive as the rippedView is position at (x: 0, y: 0). When I try force a new frame onto this view its tough because Im guessing the pixel perfect correct frame. Here’s a bit of the code from my viewController:

```
/* 
 I tried to make insertionView and imposeView have the same dimensions as the scrollView and 
 the stackView respectively as I thought if the rippedView’s original superView is the same 
 dimensions as it’s new superView, the rippedView would be positioned in the same place 
 without me needing to alter its frame.
 */


let insertionView = UIView(frame: scrollView.frame)
let imposeView = UIView(frame: stackView.frame) 

rippedView.removeFromSuperview()
insertionView.addSubview(imposeView)
imposeView.addSubview(rippedView)

let newFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 450, width: rippedView.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: 
rippedView.intrinsicContentSize.height)

rippedView.frame = newFrame
self.view.addSubview(insertionView)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Before** removing `rippedView`, get it's actual frame:

```
let newFrame = self.view.convert(rippedView.bounds, from: rippedView)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The convert method was really helpful in getting me to a solution. At the end of the day I had to meld the convert method you mentioned and some of @DonMag's code, specifically `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to true part.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are hitting is likely due to the stackView's arranged subviews having `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false`. I believe this happens automatically when you add a view to a stackView, unless you specify otherwise.

A stackView's arranged subviews have coordinates relative to the stackView itself. So the first view will be at `0,0`. Since you are adding a "container" view with the same frame as the stackView, you can use the same coordinate space... but you'll need to enable `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`.

Try it like this:

```
@objc func btnTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {

    // get a reference to the 3rd arranged subview in the stack view
    let rippedView = stackView.arrangedSubviews[2]

    // local var holding the rippedView frame (as set by the stackView)
    // get it before moving view from stackView
    let r = rippedView.frame

    // instantiate views
    let insertionView = UIView(frame: scrollView.frame)
    let imposeView = UIView(frame: stackView.frame)

    // add imposeView to insertionView
    insertionView.addSubview(imposeView)

    // add insertionView to self.view
    self.view.addSubview(insertionView)

    // move rippedView from stackView to imposeView
    imposeView.addSubview(rippedView)

    // just to make it easy to see...
    rippedView.backgroundColor = .green

    // set to TRUE
    rippedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

    // set the frame
    rippedView.frame = r
}
```

Here's a full class example that you can run directly (just assign it to a view controller):

```
class RipViewViewController: UIViewController {

    let aButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        v.setTitle("Testing", for: .normal)
        return v
    }()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        return v
    }()

    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.spacing = 8
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(aButton)

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let sg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            aButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            aButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),

            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -40.0),

            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),

        ])

        for i in 1...5 {
            let l = UILabel()
            l.backgroundColor = .cyan
            l.textAlignment = .center
            l.text = "Label \(i)"
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(l)
        }

        aButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func btnTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {

        // get a reference to the 3rd arranged subview in the stack view
        let rippedView = stackView.arrangedSubviews[2]

        // local var holding the rippedView frame (as set by the stackView)
        // get it before moving view from stackView
        let r = rippedView.frame

        // instantiate views
        let insertionView = UIView(frame: scrollView.frame)
        let imposeView = UIView(frame: stackView.frame)

        // add imposeView to insertionView
        insertionView.addSubview(imposeView)

        // add insertionView to self.view
        self.view.addSubview(insertionView)

        // move rippedView from stackView to imposeView
        imposeView.addSubview(rippedView)

        // just to make it easy to see...
        rippedView.backgroundColor = .green

        // set to TRUE
        rippedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

        // set the frame
        rippedView.frame = r

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a solution by mixing the code you and @Yonat shared.